Update REST API Payload using before Plugin
Can I use before plugin in Magento 2 to update Customer Creation Payload?
Reason: In Magento, we have one custom customer attribute of dropdown type as you can see below.

Now the API is working fine if we set the custom attribute in Payload as follow.
"custom_attributes": [
    {
        "attribute_code": "account_type",
        "value": "8" // to set "Owner" or "9" to set Tenant
    }
]

But we want to allow input values as "Owner" & "Tenant" instead of int values which might change in future.
To approach this problem, I am planning to write before Plugin following method.

Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::createAccount()

But before reaching my plugin code, it reaches the validate() method and return me following error.

"Error occurred during "custom_attributes" processing. Attribute
"account_type" has invalid value. The "Owner" value's type is
invalid. The "int" type was expected. Verify and try again."

Means before I anticipate the Post data, it validates and throw error.
Q#1 Is this the right approach? Or should I go for preferences?
Q#2 Which method I need to plugin here that allow me to read the POST data and update it (replace "Owner" with "8" and "Tenant" with "9") and proceed with registration?
